# How can i make an application installed from sourse to be able to work as "enviroment variable" in linux command line

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, centos6

For personal preference reasons , and updating simplicity, i prefer the installation location /opt (when i install from source).

But for example if i install node or ffmpeg to /opt (./configure --prefix=/opt) the commands are not available in command line, but if i wouldn't use the prefix it would.
I should be creating i guess a script but i have no idea to which location and how.

Some more detail: I have installed nginx server in /opt/ , and i have created an executable script in /etc/init.d/ and its working fine, but i have no idea how to do that with node or ffmpeg since as far as i know they are not service but something more like "environment variables".

Any solution appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Have you added `/opt/...` to your `$PATH`?

Comment: And no, node and ffmpeg are not environment variables. They're executables. And if you want to be able to execute them without supplying their full paths, their respective parent directories will have to be in `$PATH`. If this is beyond your knowledge, then may I suggest *not* installing in non-standard prefixes?

Comment: @Biffen no i havent added /opt/... to my $PATH , i never again in the past faced with a situation like this. How can i do that exactly?

Is it just 
`PATH=$PATH:/opt/ffmpeg
export PATH`
and thats all?

Comment: Or is better to do
`# echo 'pathmunge /opt/ffmpeg' > /etc/profile.d/ffmpeg.sh
# chmod +x /etc/profile.d/ffmpeg.sh`

Comment: Something like that, if `/opt/ffmpeg` is the directory that contains the executable. It's up to you.

Comment: For the shared libraries to be shared, I also had to go to `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/ ` and i added a file named `ffmpeg.conf` containing `/opt/ffmpeg/lib` .
Then on terminal i executed `# ldconfig` and everything is working now.